# Restrict property from being rdf:type

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

In a query like this, how can I avoid `?p` being bound to `rdf:type`?

```
select ?p ?c where {
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Istance_1> ?p ?c.
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Istance_2> ?p ?c.
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `filter` to your query:

```
select ?p ?c where {
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Istance_1>  ?p ?c.
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Istance_2>  ?p ?c.
  filter( ?p != rdf:type )
}
```

It's typical to use the prefix `dbpedia:` for `http://dbpedia.org/resource/`, and I expect that `Istance` is suppose to be `Instance`, so with a bit of cleanup, you'll have

```
prefix dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/resource>
select ?p ?c where {
  dbpedia:Instance_1 ?p ?c .
  dbpedia:Instance_2 ?p ?c .
  filter( ?p != rdf:type )
}
```

If you're copying and pasting into the [public DBpedia SPARQL endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql), you won't need to define that prefix because it, and [bunch of others are predefined](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?nsdecl), but if you'll calling it some other fashion, you will need to.